# Parts of code skipped when calling functions in a function

Tags: function, loops, python-2.7, input, arguments

I'm working on a online tutorial on Python 2.7 and on exercice is to make a basic text 
game. I'm very new to programming, and still working on the basics. I wish to make "move"-function I can call in all the "rooms" in the game, and deside the movement with args. The rooms in the game will be other functions i will call in the "move"-function.

In the example below i want to make it possible to choose for 4 directions using inputs n,e,s,w but only one will take the player to the next "room"-function called room_1 (not shown in the code here).

My problem is that it does not ask for input, but jumps straight to my room_1 function. It's not even printing the print "where do you wanna go? \n"

```
def move(north, dest_n, east, dest_e, south, dest_s, west, dest_w):    
    while True:

        print "Where do you wanna go? \n"

        movement = raw_input()

        if movement in "n":
            print north
            dest_n

        elif movement in "e":
            print east
            dest_e

        elif movement in "s":
            print south
            dest_s

        elif movement in "w":
            print west
            dest_w

        else:
            print "Not a valid direction. \n"
            print "Use n, e, s, or w to move."

move(
    "the door is locked!", '',
    "You are not going that way.", '', 
    "Wall.. nope, not that way!", '',
    "You move through the corridor", room_1()
    )
```

Sorry if im being unclear about something, as I'm new to programming:)

Thanks!